# What sources of funding do faculty in Computer Science dept. in US universities have other than NSF?

Tags: professorship, funding

I made the question a bit more specific (location:US, discipline: CS) as I'm interested in answers pertaining to those details, but I can make it completely generic if the community so suggests...

By funding, I mean grants awarded to faculty as PI/co-PI for supporting Research Assistant-ships, travel to conferences, equipment acquirement etc.

*My motivation behind the question, if its relevant, is whether I can use the [NSF website](http://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch) as an exclusive source for looking up whether a particular faculty can support more students - if there are other sources of grants, doing just that would not paint a complete picture! As to my reasons for looking up faculty funding, its just so that I can answer emails from prospective applicants to the PhD program which ask "Do u know if Prof. X in your dept. has funding for new students" with a one-liner - look it up on the NSF page!*

Comment: I think it depends on the nature of your research and its potential applications.  Alternative funding sources include NASA, Dept. of Energy, Dept. of Defense, Natl. Inst. of Health, etc.

Comment: This question is based on the fundamentally flawed premise that publicly available award recipient information includes a detailed budget.  Just because someone received a million dollars from a funding agency doesn't mean that they have funding for students available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I can think of American CS faculty who have been supported by grants, contracts, or gifts from each of the following:

- US funding agencies: DARPA, Department of Defense, Department of Energy, National Instutites of Health, Department of Homeland Security, Office of Naval Research, Army Research Office, Department of Education, NASA, ...
- Foreign funding agencies (usually in concert with NSF, for international collaborations): Deutsche Forshungsgemeinschaft (Germany), Centre national de la recherche scientifique (France), Israeli Science Foundation, Danish National Research Foundation, ...
- Private foundations: Sloan, Packard, Simons, Fulbright, Guggenheim, ...
- Industry: Google, Microsoft, Facebook, Cisco, Boeing, Adobe, NVidia, ...

Comment: Industry: Yahoo, SRC

Comment: @JeffE - Interesting list! Do the other grant agencies (the government ones especially) publish their list of annual award recipients?

Comment: I don't know, but I'd be surprised if they didn't; Congress likes to see where its money goes.  A quick Google search pulls up an [Award Search page](http://science.energy.gov/funding-opportunities/award-search/) for DOE Office of Science.  I assume other federal grant agencies have something similar, especially since they almost all use [the same backend system](http://www.research.gov/) (shudder) to manage grants.

Comment: Federal agencies, in particular, probably do publish most of their awardees (and, if they don't, you could probably use an FOIA request for non-classified stuff,) but I wouldn't be surprised if some private companies working on proprietary projects or government organizations working on classified projects withhold that information.

Comment: Just to elaborate on what's been said: I worked under a professor whose lab was funded almost entirely by Google, and only a small amount by the University and the NSF itself. If you're seeing if a professor has the budget for you, see if their lab has a web page that lists funding. In any case, don't assume that university/NSF funding represents 100% of the pie.